# Want Ringtone through speaker even if earphone is plugged in 640 XL LTE

Tags: ringtone

In my previous Lumia 720, I could hear ringtone through speaker even if earphone was plugged in. But in 640 XL LTE earphone cancels ringtone noise through speaker so I have to constantly keep earphone in ears or unplug it. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn it on by setting the **Ringer On**.

To do this

1. Plug in your earphone
2. Press volume up/down button
3. Press the down arrow at the top right

[image]

4. Select the ringer on. ( After selection it should appear in your acent color )

[image: RingerON][image: Ringeroff]

If you set the **Ringer off** (see below pic) you will not hear ringtone on speaker but you will still hear it on earphone.

Comment: This works when you want to listen ringtone through earphone. I want to listen it on speaker even if earphone is plugged in, in case I forget to unplug it while leaving my seat. It is available in all my other lumia phones as well as samsung phones also.

Comment: @Aditi If you have set the **Ringer on** the ringtone will play on Speaker even if your ear phone is connected. The ringtone will play on your earphone when when ringer is off. I works for me.

Comment: It works for other phones but not Lumia 640. My ringer is on, still I am unable to hear ringtone through speaker when earphone is plugged in.

Comment: @Aditi could be a problem in ear phone jack. Try contacting service care.